# #1072 - Key column 'role_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add foreign key on my other table but this gave me error
`#1072 - Key column 'role_id' doesn't exist in table`

I have created a table named `role`

then I created like this

```
create table role (
  role_id varchar(15)
  primary key (role_id)
)
```

then when I try to alter table on my `user` table

```
alter table user
add foreign key (role_id)
references role(role_id)
```

and I got an error like this

`#1072 - Key column 'role_id' doesn't exist in table`

Comment: Hmm, I guess that the column with name `role_id` indeed doesn't exist. I suggest you use some kind of GUI database builder, instead of writing all this with your hand.

Comment: It seems that `role_id` column does not exist in `user` table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to have the column you reference in `add foreign key (`**role_id**`)` inside your user table. Otherwise you get that error.

You would have to have inside your user table something like:

```
create table user(
  ...
  role_id varchar(15)
  ...
)
```

Or if you don't have it, you have to do:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN role_id VARCHAR(15)
```

Before you set it as a foreign key.

Comment: You did that in role table, not in user. You have to have inside the user table something like `role_id varchar(15)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `role_id` inside your new table also then set it to foreign key.

```
alter table user
roll_id varchar(15),
add foreign key (role_id)
references role(role_id)
```

Edit: I don't know the proper syntax since I am new to DBMS but I had a similar error so just declare `role_id` again in the new table and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

The Table `user` does not have the column `role_id`